# Manage Office accent colors with Office Javascript API

Tags: office-js

I'm writing a PowerPoint enterprise plugin to manage our customer's color themes. I need to read / set Office color themes, **including accent colors**.

I see there is a `Office.context.officeTheme` property, but there are only 4 of a total of 12 colors. Also, when I change one of the colors, it creates a new color pallete rather than modify the current pallete.

Is there a better way to manage color themes with Office JS? Maybe a hacky way with XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention! Currently there is no direct API to operate PowerPoint themes, We track Office Add-in feature requests on our [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions), please add your request there.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that the API can't even set (or get) theme accent colors!